# How to create an Optimization in OpenMDAO framework using apply_nonlinear?

Tags: python, openmdao

I tried to optimize the Rosebrock function that relates with a simple implicit equation (see apply_nonlinear section) as shown below using OpenMDAO framework.

```
from openmdao.api import Component, Problem, Group, ScipyOptimizer, IndepVarComp, Newton, ScipyGMRES

class optimization(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        super(optimization, self).__init__()

        # Parameter
        self.add_param('x', 0.5)
        #Design Variable
        self.add_param('d1', 1.0)
        self.add_param('d2', 1.0)
        #Iteration Variable
        self.add_state('y', 1.0)
        self.add_state('z', 1.0)
        self.add_output('f', shape=1)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):

        d1 = params['d1']
        d2 = params['d2']
        y = unknowns['y']
        z = unknowns['z']

        a = y/5.833333;
        b = z/2.666667*100;

        # print('a=%f'% a)
        # print('b=%f'% b)
        # Exact value for a and b is 1 and 100

        # Rosenbrock function for Optimization
        unknowns['f'] = (a-d1)**2 + b*(d2-d1**2)**2

    def apply_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):

        x = params['x']
        y = unknowns['y']
        z = unknowns['z']

        resids['y'] = x*z + z - 4
        resids['z'] = x + 2*z - y

if __name__ == "__main__":

    top = Problem()

    root = top.root = Group()

    root.add('p1', IndepVarComp('x', 0.9))
    root.add('p2', IndepVarComp('y', 0.9))
    root.add('p', optimization())


    root.connect('p1.x', 'p.d1')
    root.connect('p2.y', 'p.d2')


    top.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
    top.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

    top.driver.add_desvar('p1.x', lower=-50, upper=50)
    top.driver.add_desvar('p2.y', lower=-50, upper=50)
    top.driver.add_objective('p.f')

    # Tell these components to finite difference
    root.p.deriv_options['type'] = 'fd'
    root.p.deriv_options['form'] = 'central'
    root.p.deriv_options['step_size'] = 1.0e-4

    top.root.nl_solver = Newton()
    top.root.nl_solver.options['maxiter']=int(200)
    top.root.nl_solver.options['atol']=float(1e-12)
    top.root.nl_solver.options['rtol']=float(1e-10)
    top.root.nl_solver.options['iprint']=int(2)

    top.root.ln_solver = ScipyGMRES()
    top.root.ln_solver.options['iprint']=int(-1)
    top.setup()
    top['p1.x'] = 0.9
    top['p2.y'] = 0.9
    top.run()

    print('\n')
    print('Minimum of %f found at (%f, %f)' % (top['p.f'], top['p.d1'], top['p.d2']))
    print('\nImplicit equation solution is')
    print('x=%f, y=%f, z=%f' % (top['p.x'], top['p.y'], top['p.z']))
```

This gives the solution as shown below,

```
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: [ 0.81999991]
            Iterations: 1
            Function evaluations: 1
            Gradient evaluations: 1
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------
Minimum of 0.820000 found at (0.900000, 0.900000)

Implicit equation solution is
x=0.500000, y=5.833333, z=2.666667
```

The solution for implicit equation is correct. But the solution for optimization doesn't seem complete. The expected solution is like design variable (d1,d2) nearly equal to one and minimum function value is nearly zero. The optimization ends up with just only one iteration. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Mixed implicit/explicit components can be a little tricky in OpenMDAO 1.x. The issue is that you didn't define an residual for the `f` output. Even though you added it as an explicit variable, since you define your own apply_nonlinear you  need to give a residual for it anyway. With out that residual equation, the finite-differencing can't get derivatives of the `f` variables. 
Its better just to define it as a state.

```
from openmdao.api import Component, Problem, Group, ScipyOptimizer, IndepVarComp, Newton, ScipyGMRES

class optimization(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        super(optimization, self).__init__()

        # Parameter
        self.add_param('x', 0.5)
        #Design Variable
        self.add_param('d1', 1.0)
        self.add_param('d2', 1.0)
        #Iteration Variable
        self.add_state('y', 1.0)
        self.add_state('z', 1.0)
        self.add_state('f', shape=1)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):

        d1 = params['d1']
        d2 = params['d2']
        y = unknowns['y']
        z = unknowns['z']

        a = y/5.833333;
        b = z/2.666667*100;

        # print('a=%f'% a)
        # print('b=%f'% b)
        # Exact value for a and b is 1 and 100

        # Rosenbrock function for Optimization
        unknowns['f'] = (a-d1)**2 + b*(d2-d1**2)**2

    def apply_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):

        d1 = params['d1']
        d2 = params['d2']
        x = params['x']
        y = unknowns['y']
        z = unknowns['z']

        a = y/5.833333;
        b = z/2.666667*100;

        resids['y'] = x*z + z - 4
        resids['z'] = x + 2*z - y
        resids['f'] = (a-d1)**2 + b*(d2-d1**2)**2 - unknowns['f']

if __name__ == "__main__":

    top = Problem()

    root = top.root = Group()

    root.add('p1', IndepVarComp('x', 0.9))
    root.add('p2', IndepVarComp('y', 0.9))
    root.add('p', optimization())


    root.connect('p1.x', 'p.d1')
    root.connect('p2.y', 'p.d2')


    top.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
    top.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

    top.driver.add_desvar('p1.x', lower=-50, upper=50)
    top.driver.add_desvar('p2.y', lower=-50, upper=50)
    top.driver.add_objective('p.f')

    # Tell these components to finite difference
    root.p.deriv_options['type'] = 'fd'
    root.p.deriv_options['form'] = 'central'
    root.p.deriv_options['step_size'] = 1.0e-4

    top.root.nl_solver = Newton()
    top.root.nl_solver.options['maxiter']=int(200)
    top.root.nl_solver.options['atol']=float(1e-12)
    top.root.nl_solver.options['rtol']=float(1e-10)
    top.root.nl_solver.options['iprint']=int(2)

    top.root.ln_solver = ScipyGMRES()
    top.root.ln_solver.options['iprint']=int(-1)
    top.setup()
    top['p1.x'] = 0.9
    top['p2.y'] = 0.9
    top.run()

    print('\n')
    print('Minimum of %f found at (%f, %f)' % (top['p.f'], top['p.d1'], top['p.d2']))
    print('\nImplicit equation solution is')
    print('x=%f, y=%f, z=%f' % (top['p.x'], top['p.y'], top['p.z']))
```